# what does a private variable really mean?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a form called form1  and I also have a class called class1
when I tried to get the text in a textbox in form1 from class1. it literally took me two days to figure out the correct way to get the text.

see code below:

I have the following class:

```
class Class1
{
                   // field to hold the Form1 object reference
    private Form1 DataEntryForm;

   // Class1 constructor
    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
       // store the Form1 object reference
        DataEntryForm = form;    
    }


    public void gettext()
    {
         //the following doesn't work..
        string textintextbox = DataEntryForm.textBox1.text;
        //I get the following error =>  somenamespace.Form1.textBox1 is inaccessible due to its protection 


//but the following code works just fine.... why?
        textintextbox =   ((TextBox)DataEntryForm.Controls.Find("textBox1",true).FirstOrDefault()).Text;
    }
}
```

as you can see I knew i had to declare a reference to the form in class1 and then access the textbox like so 'myform1refence.textbox1.text" but if you look at the code above this didn't work as the textbox1 is private. so i Google like I was possessed for workaround to this and everywhere I went, people suggested I "SHOULD NOT" make The textBox1 public as it's bad programming or something but i Should create a public variable like so

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public sometype somevariablename {get { return somePrivatevariablename; } set { somePrivatevariablename = value; }}
}
```

so I thought this is the correct way I should access my textbox1 from class1 so I wrote the following

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public TextBox _textBox1 {get { return this.textBox1; } set { this.textBox1 = value; }}
}
```

so when I type the following in class1 it works!

exhibition A

```
 string textintextbox = DataEntryForm.textBox1.text;
```

so for a day i went on coding and accepted this to be the best solution to my problem. Then by accident i stumbled onto the following code:

exhibition B

```
 string textintextbox =    ((TextBox)DataEntryForm.Controls.Find("textBox1",true).FirstOrDefault()).Text;
```

with the above code I didn't need to make textbox1 public on create a public getter and setter for textBox1 all I needed to do was create a form1 reference.

So my question is why does exhibition B work with only a reference to a form but
exhibition A needs both a reference to the form and the the variable being accessed to be public to work. why is this...what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to better understand what's happening *under the hood*, I recommend you to install [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). Open `System.Windows.Forms` from the GAC and take a look at the `Control` class.

The exhibit B **will work** because the `Controls` property of the `System.Windows.Form.Control` class contains all the controls, disregarding their modifiers:

```
public Control.ControlCollection Controls
{
    get
    {
        Control.ControlCollection controlCollection = (Control.ControlCollection)this.Properties.GetObject(Control.PropControlsCollection);
        if (controlCollection == null)
        {
            controlCollection = this.CreateControlsInstance();
            this.Properties.SetObject(Control.PropControlsCollection, controlCollection);
        }
        return controlCollection;
    }
}
```

Where `CreateControlsInstance` is:

```
protected virtual Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
{
    return new Control.ControlCollection(this);
}
```

So the `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Find` method, which is `public`, searches the specidfied control name over the **whole** control collection:

```
public Control[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key", SR.GetString("FindKeyMayNotBeEmptyOrNull"));
    }
    ArrayList arrayList = this.FindInternal(key, searchAllChildren, this, new ArrayList());
    Control[] array = new Control[arrayList.Count];
    arrayList.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Exhibit A relies on a public member referencing the component. If the component does not exist, the designer-generated field (`this.textBox1`)  won't exist either and the program will fail to compile.

Exhibit B finds the component by name. If the component does not exist, the program will compile just fine but then fail *at run time*.

Compilation errors are usually preferred to run-time errors in this context, but the right choice ultimately depends on your quality requirements.

Comment: Sorry you lost me when you said "the right choice only depends on your quality requirements" what do you mean in this sentence? Are you saying that both approaches are correct? how so if exhibition A requires more work/code?

Comment: @Fabio, in terms of end results, both solutions are "correct". One of them, as you say, implies writing more code but is more robust (errors will happen during development, at compile time, before the product ships). The other requires less code but is less robust (eventual errors will happen at runtime, i.e. during tests or even possibly after the product has been shipped). That's why I said the choice is yours and depends on your quality requirements.

Comment: @Hamidi  So if I understand you correctly.. lets say I misspelled the control's name in exibition B that error won't show up at compile time but will show up instead when exibition B code is finally run? or at run-time? so I have to personally make sure that that control exist and the name is correctly spelled as the compiler can't detect this at compile time?

Comment: @Fabio, yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class1
{
    public string getText()
    {
        return DataEntryForm.textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

is probably what you want. `getText` is public - it can be called by something outside the class:

```
Class1 Thingy = new Class1();
string AString = Thingy.getText();
```

but will stop you accessing the class internals. This won't be allowed

```
string AnotherString = Thingy.textBox1.Text;
```

And nor will this:

```
TextBox tb = Thingy.textBox1;
```

BUT, you could add this function to you class keeping your text-box private:

```
public TextBox GetMyTextBox()
{
    return textBox1;
}
```

From outside the class you can do:

```
string Str = Thingy.GetMyTextBox().Text;
```

The point here is that the actual variables remain private to the class, and what you make public is via member functions only. This is encapsulation.

I'd strongly recommend you read up on basic object-oriented principles - find an online tutorial on it or something! Best of luck.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question...I already understand what you demonstrated. But if you read the whole question, you will see that exhibition B accesses a private variable "textbox" in form1 class from class1. If what you are saying is true why doesn't that hold for exhibition B?

Comment: I've added some more stuff that hopefully explains a bit about what encapsulation means.